# Fluxbox - How to Configure Dual Monitors?

Tags: multiple-monitors, fluxbox

I have a nVidia 9800 video card and I previously setup my screen through the nVidia X Server Settings tool. But when I switch from Gnome to Fluxbox, it appears that my two monitors are treated as a single screen.

How do I configure my screens so that I can mouse between them and have separate background images, etc?

**UPDATE:**  Here is my current xorg.conf file:

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 1.0  (buildd@yellow)  Fri Apr  9 11:51:21 UTC 2010

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "ACI ASUS VH236H"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 85.0
    VertRefresh     55.0 - 75.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce 9800 GTX+"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "TwinView" "1"
    Option         "TwinViewXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-0"
    Option         "metamodes" "DFP-0: nvidia-auto-select +1920+0, DFP-1: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 1.0  (buildd@yellow)  Fri Apr  9 11:51:21 UTC 2010

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "ACI ASUS VH236H"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 85.0
    VertRefresh     55.0 - 75.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce 9800 GTX+"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "TwinView" "1"
    Option         "TwinViewXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-0"
    Option         "metamodes" "DFP-0: nvidia-auto-select +1920+0, DFP-1: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What VGA do you use? If Nvidia, nvidia has own video configuration called [`nvidia-settings`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/alt-nvidia-current-settings.1.html).

[image: screenshot]

Comment: @squallbayu - I have an nVidia card. The nvidia-settings tool is the same as what I mentioned in the post. For some reason that tool is now treating my two screens as a single screen. I need to work with them as two separate screens.

Comment: do you mean twin view? if yes, just go to the X Server Display Configuration menu, then select 'Configure...' button in configure menu. select twin-view. after that, select apply for change.

Comment: Its already setup with Twinview, but it still only recognizes the monitors as a single screen. What I'm looking for is information on how to force it to see them as two screens.

Comment: do you mean Xinerama?

Comment: @squallbayu - No I mean Twinview. But just to be fair when I get home later I'll update my question with the output from xorg.conf.

Comment: @squallbayu - I've posted my xorg.conf file.

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can do is unhook one monitor, restart your computer, and then redetect the displays.  That should get it (that's what I've had to do in the past, at least).

Answer (score 2):

What about [GRandR](ftp://ftp.freedesktop.org/pub/individual/app/) ([git](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/grandr/))?

Go in the Software Center and search for "grandr", install it and try it. Not available anymore on Ubuntu 16.04+.

Also you have [ARandR](https://christian.amsuess.com/tools/arandr/), *Another XRandR GUI* and [grandr-applet](https://sites.google.com/site/kdekorte2/grandr_applet) (not related).